# Row wise count # in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted the counts of records row wise in sql.

```
+----------+-------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Products | Totel | sellers=COUNT(C2:F2) | seller a | seller b | seller c | seller d |
+----------+-------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| a        |     3 | 23.4                 | 34.2     | null     | 34.2     |          |
| b        |     2 | 23.4                 | null     | 34.2     | null     |          |
| c        |     1 | 23.4                 | null     | null     | null     |          |
| d        |     4 | 23.4                 | 34.2     | 34.2     | 34.2     |          |
+----------+-------+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I can do this in excel using this =COUNT(C2:F2).
How to do in sql?

Comment: do you mean you want to count the not number of not-null columns in a single row of the result?

Comment: `GROUP BY` may help to get the row wise count

Comment: This question isn't quite clear. If you want this in a table and as an invariant, I would use a computed column; otherwise you can replicate the results using the SUM/CASE/GROUP BY method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select sum(
    case when [seller a] is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when [seller b] is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when [seller c] is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when [seller d] is null then 0 else 1 end
)
from your_table
```

This will give the total for all rows as it doesn't seem obvious how to group it otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, corrected my answer, at first I thought you wanted sum not count.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but will need `GROUP BY`

```
Select 
Products,
sum(
      case when SellerA is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when SellerB is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when SellerC is null then 0 else 1 end
    + case when SellerD is null then 0 else 1 end
) AS Total_Seller,
SellerA,
SellerB,
SellerC,
SellerD
from MyTable
GROUP BY
Products,
SellerA,
SellerB,
SellerC,
SellerD
```

Alternately, you can also use this.

```
Select 
Products,
ISNULL((SellerA/SellerA),0)
+ISNULL((SellerB/SellerB),0)
+ISNULL((SellerC/SellerC),0)
+ISNULL((SellerD/SellerD),0) AS Total_Seller,
SellerA,
SellerB,
SellerC,
SellerD
from MyTable
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01daa/7)